# How do you load data into a Table View when there's both a Tab Bar and a Nav Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I think I'm [way overthinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755335/tab-bar-and-nav-controller-where-did-i-go-wrong-in-my-interface-builder-wiring) the issue of having a Tab Bar project type and adding Nav Bar controls. I've followed some [basic directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller) and have a demo app running fine with two tabs, each with a Table View and nav bars. But how do I load data into them? I know I need to hook up `delegate` and `dataSource`, but where?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider storing the root controllers of each tab's `UINavigationController` in separate NIB files too; you will set the file's owner in each controller as the controller and hook up your UITableView's datasource and delegate to the file's owner.

[Apple's Interface Builder documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/BuildingaNibFile/BuildingaNibFile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005344-CH11-SW1) has some good advice on keeping your NIB files small.

Answer (score 0):

You datasource and delegate is typically the same object and the "View Controller" in your hierarchy. You can have them extend `UITableViewController` and have much of the work done for you.

Comment: OK, great, thanks! And in this case is "View Controller (Item)" a delegate of anything?